# Changing language in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I have a multilingual tool. It works great in several languages, Such as English, French, German and Spanish. I'm trying to add support for Simplified Chinese. The issue is that I need to switch the font family to a font that supports Chinese characters.

In my code I've put some logic to switch to a font that supports Chinese but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$lang = 'zh';
...
$pdf->SetFont(($lang == 'zh' ? 'cid0cs' : 'Helvetica'), 'I', 8);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In what way exactly "it doesn't seem to work"? And more of you code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **msungstdlight** for Simplified / Traditional Chinese.

Sample code:
$pdf->SetFont('msungstdlight','',9);

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (except if you consider my example text is not in simplified chinese) :

```
<?php
// Include the main TCPDF library
require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');
// Create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// Set font
$lang = 'zh';
$pdf->SetFont(($lang == 'zh' ? 'cid0cs' : 'Helvetica'), 'I', 8);

// Add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
<p>简化字</p>
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('test_TCPDF.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a fiddle to share by any chance?

Comment: Do you know any online php editor which implements the TCPDF library ?